# Há como adicionar mais de uma máscara em um JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, gui

Eu tenho `JFormattedTextField` para um atributo 'preço'.

Nele digo que seu formato é "R$ #####,##". Porém, como ainda não sei adicionar eventos (estou aprendendo) gostaria desde já se é necessário (e possível) uma nova máscara (e como, se for o caso), por exemplo, para valores `R$ ###,##` ou ainda `R$ ##,##`, pois nem sempre os valores serão na faixa de milhar, porém gostaria de ter um formato, como o já indicado.

Answer (score 1):

@JNMarcos não creio que exista sem extender e criar seu próprio FormatterFactory. Mas você pode utilizar uma solução simples como:

```
jFormattedTextField.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.PERSIST);
```

Desta forma quando o formattedTextField perder o foco ele não apagará o valor do campo. (Isso transformará seu formattedTextField em um jTextField normal).

Você pode usar um field e tratar com um evento de listener o valor:

field.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

```
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            jFormattedTextField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    String text = jFormattedTextField.getText();

                    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                        int indexOf = text.indexOf(",");//index da vírgula, se é -1 é por que não existe.

                        if (indexOf == -1) {//não existe vírgula, então completa-se com ",00"
                            text = text + ",00";

                        } else {

                            String aposVirgula = text.substring(indexOf + 1);

                            int decimais = aposVirgula.length();//obtém o tamanho do texto após a vírgula

                            if (decimais == 0) {//se Zero, é porque o valor está dessa forma "1000,"
                                text = text + "00";//então completa-se com o 2 zeros

                            } else if (decimais == 1) {// se Um então , é porque o valor está dessa forma "1000,0"
                                text = text + "0";//então completa-se com o 1 zero
                            }
                        }

                        try {
//Fazendo isso, note que seu field permite que insira caracteres. Por isso você precisará checar se o valor é um numero válido.
                            Float.valueOf(text.replace(",", "."));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException er) {
                            text = null;
                        }
                        field.setText(text);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Eu lhe sugiro utilizar utilizar [um Document no JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/0200__Document.htm) ao invés desse código.